# label control not changing color and date function not working as intended

Tags: javascript, microsoft-appstudio

i have an appstudio form that in theory is supposed to take the input date of an item's expiration and return a message in the label control in orange if date is within 5 days and red if within 3 days. at this time the code runs without error codes but does not change color for the label.

controls include:
an input control for date 'inptDate'
label that changes color and text  to show days remaining 'lblShowExp'
a submit button 'btnSubmit'
a label that shows error codes related to

here is the code i tried:

```
let pw = 'BIA375'
let myDatabase = 'fmt17871'
let allFoods = {}
let results 

btnSubmit.onclick = function() {
  query = "SELECT ExpirationDate FROM ingredients WHERE ingredientName='Apples'"

  req = Ajax("https://ormond.creighton.edu/courses/375/ajax-connection.php", "POST", "host=ormond.creighton.edu&user=" + netID + "&pass=" + pw + "&database=" + myDatabase + "&query=" + query)

  if (req.status == 200) { // trip to and from database server worked
    console.log(`req.responseText is a JSON string that looks like this: ${req.responseText}`)
    results = JSON.parse(req.responseText)
    if (results.length == 0) // no results were returned by the query
      lblErrors.value = "There are no foods in the database."
    else { //  results were returned by the query
      let dataToDisplay = ""
      for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++)
        dataToDisplay = dataToDisplay + results[i][4] + "\n"

      allFoods = results


    }
  } else // trip to server DIDN'T work
    lblErrors.value = "Error code: " + req.status

}



// Function to handle the submit button click event
btnSubmit.onclick = function() {
  // Get the input date and parse it as a Date object
  const inputDate = new Date(inptDate.value);
  const currentDate = new Date();

  // Calculate the difference between the input date and the current date in days
  const dateDiff = Math.ceil((inputDate - currentDate) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

  // Check if the input date is within 5 or 3 days of the current date
  if (dateDiff <= 5 && dateDiff > 0) {
    const foodItem = 'Food item'; // Replace with the actual food item name
    lblShowExp.text = `${foodItem} expires in ${dateDiff} days`;

    // Set the text color to orange if the difference is less than or equal to 5 days
    if (dateDiff <= 5 && dateDiff > 3) {
      lblShowExp.textColor = 'orange';
    }
    // Set the text color to red if the difference is less than or equal to 3 days
    else if (dateDiff <= 3) {
      lblShowExp.textColor = 'red';
    }
  } else {
    lblShowExp.text = '';
  }
};
```